# What is the most elegant way to calculate seasonal means with R?

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I have evenly spaces timeseries with daily mean observational data.

How do I compute seasonal means the easiest way? The seasons should follow the meteorological nomenclature with DJF (=winter: December, January, February), MAM, JJA, and SON.

That means December values comes from the year x-1.

The calculation of monthly means is nicely presented here:
[How to calculate a monthly mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503813/how-to-calculate-a-monthly-mean)

It is possible to follow this idea when computing seasonal means. However, several caveats makes it not very transparent and one has to be careful!

I also dealt with a small part of this issue already in a former thread: [How to switch rows in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976078/how-to-switch-rows-in-r)

Here is now the complete story:

**0:** make a random time series

```
ts.pdsi <- data.frame(date = seq(
                from=as.Date("1901-01-01"), 
                to=as.Date("2009-12-31"), 
                by="day"))
ts.pdsi$scPDSI <- rnorm(dim(ts.foo)[1],  mean=1, sd=1)    # add some data
```

**1st:** use the seas package and add seasons to your timeseries, which has to be formatted as a data.frame.

```
library(seas)
# add moth/seasons
ts.pdsi$month  <- mkseas(ts.pdsi,"mon")   # add months
ts.pdsi$seas <- mkseas(ts.pdsi,"DJF")     # add seasons
ts.pdsi$seasyear <- paste(format(ts.pdsi[,1],"%Y"), 
                          ts.pdsi$seas ,sep="")   # add seasyears, e.g. 1950DJF
```

this gives

```
> head(ts.pdsi)
    date      scPDSI month seas seasyear
1 1901-01-01 -0.10881074   Jan  DJF  1901DJF
2 1901-02-01 -0.22287750   Feb  DJF  1901DJF
3 1901-03-01 -0.12233192   Mär  MAM  1901MAM
4 1901-04-01 -0.04440915   Apr  MAM  1901MAM
5 1901-05-01 -0.36334082   Mai  MAM  1901MAM
6 1901-06-01 -0.52079030   Jun  JJA  1901JJA
```

**2nd:** You can then calculate the seasonal means, following the above mentioned approach using the column $seasyear

```
> MEAN <- tapply(pdsi$scPDSI, ts.pdsi$seasyear, mean, na.rm = T)
> head(MEAN)
1901DJF     1901JJA     1901MAM     1901SON     1902DJF     1902JJA 
-0.45451556 -0.72922229 -0.17669396 -1.12095590 -0.86523850 -0.04031273
```

NOTE: spring (MAM) and summer (JJA) are switched due to strictley alphabetical sorting.

**3rd:** switch it back

```
foo <- MEAN
for(i in 1:length(MEAN)) {
    if (mod (i,4) == 2) {
        foo[i+1] <- foo[i]    #switch 2nd 3rd row (JJA <-> MAM)
        foo[i] <- MEAN[i+1]
    }
}
# and generate new names for the array
d <- data.frame(date=seq(from=as.Date("1901-01-01"), to=as.Date("2009-12-31"), by="+3 month"))
d$seas <- mkseas(d,"DJF") 
d$seasyear <- paste(format(d[,1],"%Y"), d$seas ,sep="")
names(foo)<-d$seasyear  # add right order colnames
MEAN <-foo
```

Finally, this results in a time series of seasonal means. Well, I fid it too complicated and i guess there are much easier solutions around.

Additionally, this solution has also a really major problem with the winter season DJF: The December is so far not choosen from the year before. This is rather easy to fix (I guess), but makes the given way eve more complicated.

I really hope there are better ideas around!

Comment: This code snippet may help: `dd <- c(Sys.Date(), as.Date(c("2013-11-30", "2013-12-01"))); season_year <- as.numeric(format(dd + 31, "%Y"))`.

Comment: good point, the snipplet might be helpful

Comment: To solve the issue of winter season (in DJF, D should be D of the year n-1), one idea is to create a "fake" year column with the value of the current year for every month except for Dec where you use n+1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I this what you want?

```
# # create some data: daily values for three years
df <- data.frame(date = seq(from = as.Date("2007-01-01"),
                            to = as.Date("2009-12-31"),
                            by = "day"))
df$vals <- rnorm(nrow(df))

# add year
df$year <- format(df$date, "%Y")

# add season
df$seas <- mkseas(x = df, width = "DJF")

# calculate mean per season within each year
df2 <- aggregate(vals ~ seas + year, data = df, mean)

df2
#    seas year         vals
# 1   DJF 2007 -0.048407610
# 2   MAM 2007  0.086996842
# 3   JJA 2007  0.013864555
# 4   SON 2007 -0.081323367
# 5   DJF 2008  0.170887946
# 6   MAM 2008  0.147830260
# 7   JJA 2008  0.003008866
# 8   SON 2008 -0.057974215
# 9   DJF 2009 -0.043437437
# 10  MAM 2009 -0.048345979
# 11  JJA 2009  0.023860506
# 12  SON 2009 -0.060076870
```

Because `mkseas` converts the dates into a seasonal factor with levels in the desired order, the order is correct also after the aggregation over year and season.

Comment: Henrik, this one looks really nice/elegantly! True, mkseas keeps the right order also for DJF.

Comment: I finally added a date variable for plotting the time series with 
>>> df2$date <- seq(from=min(df$date), to=max(df$date), by="+3 month")

Comment: This doesn't work with monthly data (where DJF covers two years), monthly solution added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier if you use numbers rather than strings for months and seasons, at least at first.  You can get the seasons you want by simple arithmetic manipulations, including making December part of the subsequent year.

```
pdsi <- data.frame(date = seq(
            from=as.Date("1901-01-01"), 
            to=as.Date("2009-12-31"), 
            by="day"))
pdsi$scPDSI <- rnorm(nrow(pdsi),  mean=1, sd=1)
pdsi$mon<-mon(pdsi$date)+1
pdsi$seas<-floor((pdsi$mon %% 12)/3)+1
pdsi$year<-year(pdsi$date)+1900
pdsi$syear<-pdsi$year
pdsi$syear[pdsi$mon==12]<-pdsi$syear[pdsi$mon==12]+1
```

To compute seasonal means, you can simply do this:

```
meanArray<-tapply(pdsi$scPDSI,list(year=pdsi$syear,seas=pdsi$seas),mean)
```

And now you have

```
>head(meanArray)
      seas
year           1         2         3         4
  1901 1.0779676 1.0258306 1.1515175 0.9682434
  1902 0.9900312 0.8964994 1.1028336 1.0074296
  1903 0.9912233 0.9858088 1.1346901 1.0569518
  1904 0.7933653 1.1566892 1.1223454 0.8914211
  1905 1.1441863 1.1824074 0.9044940 0.8971485
  1906 0.9900826 0.9933909 0.9185972 0.8922987
```

If you want it as a flat array, with appropriate names, you first take the transpose, and then flatten the array, and add the names

```
colnames(meanArray)<-c("DJF","MAM","JJA","SON")
meanArray<-t(meanArray)
MEAN<-array(meanArray)
names(MEAN)<-paste(colnames(meanArray)[col(meanArray)],rownames(meanArray)[row(meanArray)],sep="")
```

This gets you get the result you wanted

```
> head(MEAN)
  1901DJF   1901MAM   1901JJA   1901SON   1902DJF   1902MAM 
1.0779676 1.0258306 1.1515175 0.9682434 0.9900312 0.8964994
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, there can be very simple solutions (also posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/subset-data-by-month-in-r/173137#173137)). I would use a combination of the **zoo** and **seas** packages to aggregate by season, looking something like this:

```
library(zoo); library(seas)

seasTS <- aggregate(dataTS, mkseas(x=time(dataTS),width="DJF"), sum)
```

To do this for each year, simply loop over mkseas() by year. I'll have my coffee with a little syntactic sugar, please.

Cheers,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with monthly data and `aggregate` was not allowing for the DJF split over years. To get around it you can add a synthetic year column assigning December values to the following year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(seas)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(yearmonth = c("187601", "187602", "187603", "187604", "187605", "187606", "187607","187608", "187609", "187610", "187611", "187612", "187701", "187702", "187703", "187704", "187705", "187706", "187707", "187708", "187709", "187710", "187711", "187712", "187801", "187802", "187803", "187804", "187805", "187806", "187807", "187808", "187809", "187810", "187811", "187812", "187901", "187902", "187903", "187904", "187905", "187906", "187907", "187908", "187909", "187910", "187911", "187912"), 
                 SOI = rnorm(n = 48, mean = 0, sd = 4))


df %>% 
  mutate(yearmonth = lubridate::ymd(yearmonth, truncated = 1),
         year = year(yearmonth),
         month = month(yearmonth),
         seas = mkseas(yearmonth, width = "DJF"),
         year2 = ifelse(test = month == 12,
                        yes = year + 1,
                        no = year)) %>% 
  group_by(year2, seas) %>% 
  summarise(meanSOI = mean(SOI))
```