# How can I convert my 4 daily identifiers into monthly means?

Tags: r, database

Given I have the following data table:

```
      total_sales tickets_sold show_time occu_perc ticket_price       DATE
1:     3900000           26         4      4.26       150000 2018-05-05
2:     3360000           42         5      8.08        80000 2018-05-05
3:     2560000           32         4     20.00        80000 2018-05-05
4:     1200000           12         1     11.01       100000 2018-05-05
5:     1200000           15         3     16.67        80000 2018-05-05
6:     1050000            7         3      0.98       150000 2018-05-05
```

The data entails daily sales, the volume in sold tickets etc. I am intending to transform all but the DATE variable into a time series for multivariate analysis. **However**, I would like to convert the entries into aggregate monthly means, e.g., average monthly show times. How would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978256/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-calculate-seasonal-means-with-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `DATE` you can extract year and month value and aggregate the variables for each month and return the `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE), 
         ym = format(DATE, '%Y-%m')) %>%
  group_by(ym) %>%
  summarise(across(total_sales:ticket_price, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As a follow up, do you mind elaborating how that would work if I want to compute the daily mean?

Comment: You already have `DATE` variable for that. So you can remove the `mutate` line, `group_by(DATE)` and keep the `summarise` as it is.